# In a Victorian Era steampunk D&D campaign: what historic implications would it have if Scotland was underwater?

Tags: history, steampunk, victorian-era

So, this is a rather unusual question. I'm not going to talk to you about the backstory because that's another question by itself, but I want to talk about how Scotland has influenced the rest of the world in this time. Here's a couple things to clarify:

1. Scotland was underwater during the formation of Pangea we'll assume.
2. I'm only asking for what will have happened up to that point, as the title might suggest.
3. Try and be specific, would Scotland have been important to the developments in this steampunk world? (Would England have been less distracted on their conquest of them? Would some other part of mainland Europe be targetted instead?)

Thanks, I'll respond to any further questions anyone has.

Comment: So essentially how would the world look in the 1800's if Scotland never existed? First of all, i think you'll find that if Scotland was underwater, so would most of the rest of England. Second, this question is insanely broad.

Comment: Let's imagine that only some of England was drowned. The mainland part of it was spared. Lots of the small islands encircling it were drowned out. Perhaps just some _noteable_ historical events that might happen and how the world might look at that point.

Comment: I'm afraid that this sort of question is out of scope here. It's a "what-if" type of question with implications that no one person can reasonably envision.

Comment: You would all be doomed. No highland single malts, no future.

Comment: @AndreiROM Yeah, it's rather tough to consider the effects of it. I knew that no single person would give a resolute answer. I thought that perhaps the community might be able contribute multiple interesting tidbits. Also,  (No highland malts got it (What a sad world it would be indeed))

Comment: @AidanSmyth Normally you should try to ask questions that can be answered in one answer, otherwise this might be "too broad". The normal way to go about a "too broad" question is splitting it into multiple questions, often by focussing the attention on one certain aspect at a time and using the feedback you get on the follow-up questions. If you are unsure about a question we also have a [Sandbox](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/635/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) where you can test questions and get feedback on all the general stuff before asking it on Main.

Comment: ***"I thought that perhaps the community might be able contribute multiple interesting tidbits"*** <- the purpose of the site is that any one answer is comprehensive, and can objectively be chosen as "the best". Yes, multiple people can pitch in and bring more viewpoints to the table, but in this particular case it would be nearly impossible to fully answer the question. If you simply want some advice, take your question to chat. The folks there will gladly help you out.

Comment: Without Scotland, the saxons might not have reached england and the pict might no have had a refuge to regroup against the roman invasions. England could've become another latin country like France, Italy or Spain.

Comment: Perhaps kilts would not be a thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although people from Scotland have [invented a huge amount of inventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scottish_inventions_and_discoveries) including:

- James Watt's [steam engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steam_engine)
- [Tarmacadam construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macadamised)
- The [telephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone)
- [TV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Logie_Baird)

Which I guess you are referring to here, there's nothing really to suggest that the world wouldn't have invented these products (or close counterparts) someplace else.

In short, not much would have changed, unless you really want it to in your fiction.

Comment: Interesting, I ironically note that the _steam engine_ is among those. When doing a rereview of my story this will certainly come in handy. Thanks! (Still considering the effects of this)

Comment: @AidanSmyth Also economics (Adam Smith), electromagnetics (Maxwell), modern geology (James Hutton), and big chunks of mathematics (John Napier) and medicine (Patrick Manson). Turns out there's lots of time for science when the only other options are cloudy days and sheep.

Comment: And don't forget golf...what would we do without it..?

Comment: please note that the phone was invented by several people at the same time. There are many inventions that would have invented anyway, because it was time for that.